# Asp Mvc - Serve content from other locally hosted site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out a good pattern for actually writing javascript unit tests against a asp mvc website.

My idea on how to achieve this is to run two sites in parallel

- localhost:12345 - the current actual website
- localhost:54321 - the test website (set up to run jasmine)

Of course to be able to test anything of consequence, the latter would have to be able to serve up files from the former. I figure I should be able to configure a catch-all route that for any route that is not resolved on the test site, requeries the actual site with the same url and parameters and passes through the resulting response.

I know nothing that would stop this in theory but is there something I'm missing? How would you do the redirect part?